# how do you change the php version that your app uses in heroku platform?

Tags: php, heroku, composer-php

I am trying to change the PHP version that my heroku application uses from the default 7.1 to 7.0. When I try to define it in `composer.json` it is ignored. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 5):

Apart from updating composer file, if your application requires "php": ^5.6.0" or 7.0.32 you need to make sure that, heroku stack that you are using is 'heroku-16' and not 'heroku-18'.

Run `heroku stack` in CLI to get the info. By default, it is set to 'heroku-18' which is the latest version and uses Ubuntu 18.04 with PHP 7.2 installed.

If it is on 'heroku-18', use command `heroku stack:set heroku-16` to toggle.

P.S: PHP versions 5.6 and 7.0 will reach end-of-life at the end of 2018. No bugfixes, including critical security fixes, will be provided by the PHP maintainers after this date. Users are strongly encouraged to update their applications to the latest version of PHP 7.2 at their earliest convenience. For more information on support timelines for PHP releases, refer to the [Supported Versions page](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) on the official PHP website.

Answer (score 3):

From [**Selecting a runtime**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#selecting-a-runtime), you need to use `composer.json` and specify the PHP version there:

```
{
  "require": {
    "php": "^5.6.0"
  }
}
```

In your case, please have:

```
{
  "require": {
    "php": "7.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: in my composer.json i have `{
"require": {  
    "php": "~7.0"  
 }  
} `   but heroku chooses php 7.1

Comment: @GeorgeGwaro Don't use `~`.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. It locks PHP to 7.0.0 exactly, and that's a bad idea, since you always want the latest 7.0.x. You can't even run `composer update` that way unless you have that old 7.0.0 on your computer.

Comment: `~` is fine and exactly the right selector here, it just has to be used with three digits and not two.

Answer (score 2):

You need the right type of version selector. Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md

In your case, `~7.0.0` allows 7.0.0 or later, but not 7.1.

Remember to update `composer.lock` after the change, as documented at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#selecting-a-runtime (read that entire section; the orange box there actually answers exactly the question you posted here).

You really should update your code though. Support for PHP 7.0 will end in a few days, and the PHP team will no longer provide updates except for security fixes. See http://php.net/supported-versions.php

Answer (score 0):

Yo dont need to downgrade the heroku stack to 18 or anything, You can just change the required version of PHP in composer.json then run composer update against your project and finally deploy /build it to the cloud